# Unable to Setup Google Account on Android 2.3

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, samsung, google-account

After Factory Reset, In order to use Play store and Gmail I want to setup Google account on Samsung GT-S6802. When I tries to setup Google Account, In-spite of right user-name and password, following window appearers:

[image: screen-shot3]

When I open gmail form browser, I've mail from google subject:`Sign-in attempt prevented` and says:

> Someone just tried to sign in to your Google Account <s>hidden</s>@gmail.com from an app that doesn't meet modern security standards.

[image: screenshotgmail]

When I review, it shows unknown device but on browser it detects my device.

So, How do I face this issue and setup google account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem and I solved it this way:

1. Log in [here](https://myaccount.google.com/security#connectedapps) using a web browser .
2. On Login and Security, at the bottom of the page there's an option "**Allow less safe apps**" which would be set as disabled. Set it to enable and now you can log-in using your device.

   > Allow less secure apps: ON
   >
   > Some non-Google apps and devices use less secure sign-in technology, which could leave your account vulnerable. You can turn off access for these apps (which we recommend) or choose to use them despite the risks.

**Note**: The words might be a little different as I saw that Google page in Portuguese, but the option should relatively be at the same position on the page.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the direct link:
https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

But if you have 2-step-verification enable you should try generating a separate password here:
https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords